# Deep-linking with Navigation Uri issue when using strings.xml

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am checking below google sample code for test **Deep-linking with Navigation**.

[Navigation with Deep linking Basic Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample)

It works well. But in navigation.xml file I don't want to add uri directly , I want to use strings.xml file for same.

```
Not this : 
<deepLink app:uri="www.example.com/user/{userName}" />

but , Want to do like this , 

<deepLink app:uri="@string/profile_url" />
```

the reason is that, if there is any changes in URL then I just have to go in strings.xml file and replace relative things. 
Let me know if you have better idea about it or any better optimized solution.